# What is best practice for the use of Comments vs Answers?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am relatively new to Stack Overflow and as I scroll through the questions I see what I would consider answer worthy text being posted as a comment. Granted this is usually for responses that can be answered generally and don't usually contain code, but I was wondering what the best practice is for the two.

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments. If you see someone answering on comments, feel free to just reuse that as your own answer. Also use edits whenever it makes sense.

Comment: With partial credit to Temani Afif, in the comments above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to be fair, he reused the same text as the comment box placeholder.

Comment: Ah, that's funny.

Comment: Just an edit, No issue in making an answer from someone else comment if they haven't posted (or don't want to) it as an answer and by giving some credit to them in a comment or wherever we wish

Comment: @PatelRomil to fully comply with cc by-sa 3.0 you are required to provide "a link to the material". Comments, don't allow this since they can be deleted without notice.